# Desplegar en instancia AWS

Tags: python, aws

estoy desplegando un webservice en aws, ya cree mi instancia con ubuntu y configure el entorno, ejecute el python con uvicorn

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

se ejcuto con la ip http://127.0.0.1:8000 pero al momento de yo acceder desde el DNS de ipv4 publica https://ec2-3-145-3-52.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/docs no me permite ver, que puedo estar haciendo mal?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si uvicorn lo despliegas en 127.0.0.1 entonces el servicio solo será accesible desde la propia máquina. Tienes que desplegarlo en la ip pública de la máquina. Además, tienes que configurar correctamente el Security Group de la instancia para permitir las conexiones desde Internet a tu instancia.

En cualquier caso, el uso de instancias EC2 para desplegar servicios no es una buena práctica. Una instancia EC2 te está costando dinero todo el tiempo, incluso cuando nadie consume tus servicios. Es preferible desplegar esos servicios en lambdas y configurar un API Gateway para dar acceso a dichas lambdas desde Internet.

Con este otro diseño gastarás menos y conseguirás mejoras en cuanto a escalabilidad

Comment: muchas gracias crack